# Averaging as samples come in

Tags: average

I feel like this is a lot easier than I'm making it, but for some reason I just can't wrap my head around it.

Let's say I'm sampling a voltage, for argument's sake. I want to know the average voltage over a period of time. If I know the number of samples - it's simply:

$$\frac{\sum_0^n s_n}{n}$$

But, what if I'm trying to do it live? It becomes:

$$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T s(x) dx$$

But in that case, since $T$ is changing, the first sample will be weighted  most heavily, with weight decreasing over time.

Is there an easy way to get the average when I don't know how many samples I have ($n$ or $T$ in this case)? What if the number of samples is significantly large?

Comment: You can't do this without some information other than the average so far Related (from a search for _running weighted average_): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915653/how-to-calculate-iteratively-the-running-weighted-average-so-that-last-values-to

Comment: are you asking how to find [incremental averages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing?rq=1)?

Comment: Incremental averages was what I was looking for, I didn't know what it was called. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the first expression ("If I know the number of samples") has a sum of $n+1$ terms in the numerator but divides by $n$ in the denominator.