# How to choose weights for a weighted average

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, average

I have a problem where i need to calculate the running average of the number of trucks passing through a given road.

Naturally, on a good day there is a high demand for a given product, so the number of trucks increases due to an attempt to increase the supply, and vice versa.

Quoting the excellent answer given by [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) on the question: [Incremental Average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averaging). I think it is reasonable to use one of the following formulas:

***For a running average you need to keep at least two pieces of information: the number of terms so far and the running mean (or something equivalent to it).***

***Let's suppose the $n$th component of the vector is $a_n$ and the running mean up to this is $m_n$ so $$m_n= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i.$$***

***Starting with $m_0=0$, you can use the obvious single pass $$m_n = \frac{(n-1)m_{n-1}+a_n}{n}$$ but precision errors are likely to be smaller if you use the equivalent $$m_n = m_{n-1}  + \frac{a_{n}-m_{n-1}}{n}.$$***

***Using weights, instead of keeping the number of terms so far you need to keep the sum of weights so far***

***$$m_n = m_{n-1}  + \dfrac{w_n(a_{n}-m_{n-1})}{w_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} w_i}.$$***

My question is: Given the above "truck-scenario" what type of running average is most suitable, a weighted or non-weighted one. If I were to weight the data, how would I determine the weights? I have read that Inverse-variance weighting is a famous method and sometimes standard deviation or coefficient of variation is used as weights.Is there better methods?